# concurrently changing a file offset using `file.Seek` escapes the race detector?

Tags: go

in below code, the race detector does not detect the racy call to [`file.Seek`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Seek) as i expected reading the signature of the method and [its body](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/os/file.go;l=234) (assuming unix).

Can you help explaining what is going on under the hood ?

```golang
func main() {
    file, _ := os.Open("main.go")
    st, _ := file.Stat()
    max := st.Size()
    limit := int64(25)
    start := make(chan bool)
    type res struct {
        bytes.Buffer
        index int64
    }
    out := make(chan res)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := int64(0); i*limit < max; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i, limit int64) {
            <-start
            file.Seek(i*limit, 0) // This line should trigger race ? How does it work under the hood so it escapes the race detector ?
            r := res{index: i}
            io.Copy(&r, io.LimitReader(file, limit))
            out <- r
            wg.Done()
        }(i, limit)
    }
    close(start)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    var last int64
    buf := []res{}
    for o := range out {
        buf = append(buf, o)

        sort.Slice(buf, func(i int, j int) bool {
            return buf[i].index < buf[j].index
        })

        for len(buf) > 0 && buf[0].index == last {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%v\n", buf[0].String())
            // fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%v\n", buf[0].index)
            buf = append(buf[:0], buf[1:]...)
            last++
        }
    }
    sort.Slice(buf, func(i int, j int) bool {
        return buf[i].index < buf[j].index
    })
    for len(buf) > 0 {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%v\n", buf[0].String())
        // fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%v\n", buf[0].index)
        buf = append(buf[:0], buf[1:]...)
        last++
    }
    log.Println(last)
}
```

I run it with

```
$ while go run -race .; do :; done
ok
ok
ok
ok
...
```

but no luck.

Comment: No concurrent Race read writes of Go variables. The race detector doesn’t detect everything that is logigally a race.

Comment: @Volker, I see what you mean about disordered writes into discard, it was not the aspect i wanted to talk about. The call to file.Seek, i thought, should trigger a race no ?  I get lost at https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/os/file_unix.go;l=276;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.17 but i guess somewhere there is a position in memory that those multiple calls to Seek writes over many times.

Comment: `Seek` calls directly into system call. Nothing go runtime can look into.

Comment: @mh-cbon You guessed wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There *is* a race here, but the race happens outside the Go ecosystem.<sup>1</sup>  As such, the race detector—which is part of the Go ecosystem—never *sees* the race and doesn't detect it.

Note that some operating systems have `pread` and `pwrite` system calls that take a file-position argument, so that they can do atomic read/write-at-particular-position operations, rather than using two separate (and therefore race-enabling) system calls (`lseek` + `read` for instance).  If your system has these calls and also has the `readv` and `writev` calls, it probably has `preadv` and `pwritev` as well.

See also https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Pread and https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Pwrite.

---

<sup>1</sup>There could be (future) systems on which the race happens *inside* the Go ecosystem, in which case, the race detector might detect it.  I wouldn't count on it though.